# Create multiple foreign keys referes to the same table in EF code first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

In my table it has two foreign keys which refers to the same table. When I do the migration(Entity Framework Code first Approach) it pops up error as,

"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
Dog_Sire_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role `'Dog_Sire_Target'` in relationship **'Dog_Sire'**. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be **'*'.".**

But if I add only one foreign key it works properly. Here is my table structure.

```
public class Dog
{
[Key]

public int Dog_Id { get; set; }

public string Dog_Name { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Sire")]

public int? Dog_SireId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Dam")]

public int? Dog_DamId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Dog_SireId")]

public virtual Dog Sire { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Dog_DamId")]

public virtual Dog Dam { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this model:

```
public class Dog
{
    [Key]
    public int DogID { get; set; }
    public string DogName { get; set; }

    public int? DogSireID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DogSireID")]
    public virtual Dog DogSire { get; set; }

    public int? DogDamID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DogDamID")]
    public virtual Dog DogDam { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("DogSire")]
    public virtual ICollection<Dog> DogsSires { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("DogDam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Dog> DogsDams { get; set; }
}
```